# Using a combo box to filter an ID look up field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a combo box that is connected to a classTbl through classID, and and a subform which is composed of classID and studentID on a form.

The combo box filter the subform based on the classID selected and show the list of the students who are enrolled in that class. and I know how to do that without any problem.

The problem comes when I want to know the list of students WHO ARE NOT enrolled in any class show on my subform. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please modify your question to show your actual table layouts (names, field names and types).

Comment: Maybe like `SELECT * FROM Students WHERE NOT StudentID IN (SELECT StudentID FROM StudentClasses WHERE ClassID = Forms!Class!ClassID;`

Comment: Ooops, forgot closing paren for the nested query in front of semi-colon.

Comment: @june7 why do you have where classeID=Forms!class!classID? My WHERE NOT IN query is not working. It worked once before I posted this question.I messed around with it and it’s not working anymore.

Comment: Let me post the three table I am working with right now. StudentTbl: stdID, stdFName,stdLName.    classTbl: classID, className, schoolYear.      And the join table.     stdClassTbl: classID, stdID

Comment: This database is supposed to keep record of a student data from their first grade until 12th grade. I hope this is the right way  to go about. Any suggestions improving the structure of the database is welcome.

Comment: So that being said I want to find the best user friendly way to add students to their respective grade class without losing record of the old grade class. I hope that make sense

Comment: That’s how I came up with combo box and subform to filter student based on their grade class

Comment: Should edit question to show table info there. Also show SQL of attempted query.

Comment: Select StudentTbl.stdID, StudentTbl.stdFName, StudentTbl.stdLName from StudentTbl where not StudentTbl.stdID in  (select stdClassTbl.stdID FROM stdClassTbl);

Comment: This also worked for me once :                                                                                               Select StudentTbl.stdID, StudentTbl.stdFName, StudentTbl.stdLName from StudentTbl where StudentTbl.stdID not in  (select stdClassTbl.stdID FROM stdClassTbl);    But I managed to mess it around somehow